# C++ operator[] overloading with template accessing boost::variant

Tags: c++, templates, boost, operator-overloading, c++03

I've this class with a map attribute which values are boost::variant.

```
typedef boost::variant<char, int, bool, unsigned short, float, timeval, double > MultiType;

class A {
public: 
    template<class T>
    T& operator[](const std::string& key) {
        return boost::get<T>(map_[key]);
    }
    template<class T>
    std::string keyTypeToString(const std::string& key) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << boost::get<T>(map_[key]);
        return ss.str();
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, MultiType> map_; 
};
```

From main:

```
A a;
a["param"];
```

Compiler report this errors:

> ../src/main.cpp:8:25: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a["param"]’
>   ../src/main.cpp:8:25: note: candidate is:
>   ../src/util/A.h:53:5: note: template T& A::operator[](const string&)

Maybe I'm missing something trivial, but I can't understand where I'm wrong..

Comment: I see no `T` in your call of `[]`, but `operator[]` requires a `T`.  How is the compiler supposed to deduce it?  Magic?

Comment: so how should I replace a["param"] with...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A {
public:
    class proxy {
        friend class A;
    private:
        MultiType& it;
        proxy(MultiType& it): it(it) {}
    public:
        template<typename T>
          operator T&() {
            return boost::get<T>(it);
        }
    };
    proxy operator[](const std::string& key) {
        return proxy(map_[key]);
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, MultiType> map_; 
};
```

**EXPLANATION:**

*I can see that Yakk was trying similar thing.* I have encapsulated the `MultiType&` from `map_[key]` in the proxy and then left the work on conversion (type-cast) operator. That's all.

Simple `a[""]` without assignment gets you the proxy.
`double d = a["double"]` will try to convert the `proxy` to `double` and thus call `proxy::operator double&()` *(I had to test it because I was not sure if the type deduction will work as it is or will need some more work - well, it works!)*

**AFTERNOTE:** It was not clear from the question and code provided what operations are allowed. We can modify the `proxy` to allow other operations or make it more `readonly` by changing the signature of *type-conversion operator* to return `const T&` instead.

Allowing modification leads to question: **why not using `MultiType&` directly**? (returning it from `A::operator[]`) And that leads to question: why `class A` at all?

**AFTERNOTE #2:** [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) does not have type-conversion operator and there must have been a reason for it. Think about this code:

```
int i = a["double"]
```

Runtime exception! I think that best solution would be to sub-class the MultiType and define type-conversion operator there (while checking [boost::variant::which()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#id397798-bb)).

**ASSIGNING TO ALREADY PRESENT NAMES:**

```
class A { ...
    class proxy { ...
        template<class T> proxy& operator=(const T& rhs) {
            it = rhs; return *this; }
```

...but the above can only work if we already have some value in the map.

```
class A { ...
    A() { map_["pi"] = 3.14; } ...
a["pi"] = 3.1415;
```

**COMPLETE REDISIGN:**

```
class MultiType: public boost::variant<int, double, ...> {
public:
    template<class T> operator T() {
        switch(which()) {
        case 0: return boost::get<int>(*this);
        case 1: return boost::get<double>(*this);
        ...
```

Now we can use `std::map<std::string, MultiType>` directly (without `class A` or any `proxy`).

Comment: Uhm.. and then from main how I call a[""]?

Comment: the same way you did, or double d = a["double"], int i = a["int"];

Comment: Does `a["double"] = 3.0` work without an `operator=`?

Comment: no, it would have to be added on the proxy. but if we allow `operator=`, then **why using proxy**? why not returning the `MultiType&` directly? Why defining `class A` and not using the map **directly**? ....I was assuming he wants to control it in a bit different way (and we could modify the proxy to return `T` or `const T&` to ensure that our `class A` behaves like `const class A`)

Comment: I can't do a["param"] = true; I know I need to define proxy& operator[](const std::string& key); but what I have to return?

Comment: @Velthune: do you wan't to assign value of already named variable (when a["param"] is already in the set) or do you want to create it (if not already there)? In first case, you can add `operator=` on my proxy. In second case you can either use Yakk's proxy (holding parameters) or redisign the whole class - defining type conversion operator on the MultiType and get rid of all the proxy classes (best solution I think).

Comment: The only things I need is read value (for example: bool b = (bool)a["param"]) and assign (a["param"] = true). Now, if I can do it without proxies is better, but I can't understand how. ):

Comment: I see update, I was working on first solution ( operator= on proxy). By the way, why you suggest the second one (redisign)? I prefer the first one because if I need to add some type on Multitype, I don't need to modify other part of code (switch case)...

Comment: the redesign is clean, easy and adding one `case` after adding one type is no problem. ...I wonder if it could be done automatically by variadic templates... but why it isn't in boost::variant already?

Answer (score 4):

Start with this:

```
template<class T>
T& get(const std::string& key) {
    return boost::get<T>(map_[key]);
}
```

You call this like `a.get<int>("hello")`, where it will get the element `"hello"` as an `int`.

Next, write this:

```
struct pseudo_ref {
  std::string const& str;
  A* a;
  template<typename T>
  operator T&()&&{
    return a->get<T>(str);
  }
  template<typename T>
  pseudo_ref operator=( T&& t ) && {
    a->get<typename std::decay<T>::type>(str) = std::forward<T>(t);
    return {str, a};
  }
  pseudo_ref(pseudo_ref const&)=delete;
  pseudo_ref& operator=(pseudo_ref const&)=delete;
  pseudo_ref( std::string const& s, A* a_ ):str(s), a(a_) {}
};
```

then back in `A`:

```
pseudo_ref operator[](std::string const& str) {
  return {str, this};
}
```

and we get `[]` that magically converts for you, so long as you assign to it/read from it using the exactly correct type.

This is somewhat dangerous, but cool.

If you want a `const` pseudo_ref, you need another class to represent it (with no `=` and `operator T const&` instead of `operator T&`).

In practice, this kind of malarkey is rarely worth it.

I wrote this in C++11, because writing it in C++03 is slightly more painful (and runs into lifetime issues with `pseudo_ref` -- they still exist if you have an `auto&& x = a["hello"]`), and less pain is good.

Comment: Uhm.. seems complicated but could works.. I try now!

Comment: uhm.. give me "expected initializer before ‘&&’ token" at  operator T&()&&{...}

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
T& operator[](const std::string& key) {
    return boost::get<T>(map_[key]);
}
```

There's no way for the compiler to deduce `T` from a call like `a["param"];`. You'd need to specify it explicitly

```
a.operator[]<int>("param");
```

which I doubt is what you're after, but what do I know.

Comment: but "keyTypeToString" works... and the policy is the same.. isn't it?

Comment: you're code works, but if I want to use simply a[""]?

Comment: You cannot, you need to let compiler know what T is somehow.